# Is it possible to get a dynamic legend in QGIS 3.6?

Tags: qgis-3, legend, qgis-server, getlegendgraphic

I need to send a GetPrint request for a map with a dynamic legend that only shows layers/items/symbols relevant for the current map frame.

In QGIS 2.14 one can select "Filter Legend by Map Content" in the composer and export a filtered legend, but if you use a GetPrint request no legend is shown. I have managed to work my way around this by adding together GetLegendGraphics requests for each layer.

Now I'm trying to upgrade from QGIS 2.14 to QGIS 3.6, but I'm not sure this is possible. In QGIS 3.6.3 "Filter Legend by Map Content" does not seem to work in the composer and GetLegendGraphic requests are apparently ignoring the BBOX parameter.

Is this a bug? Is there any way to get around this, or do I need to keep on using QGIS 2.14?

Comment: At the fifth attempt "Filter Legend by Map Content" in composer seems to be ok. I have upgraded to 3.8, and GetLegendGraphic is still ignoring the BBOX-parameter. This works fine in 2.14.  According to [this](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html#getlegendgraphics) BBOX is supported, but I'm not having any luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getlegendgraphic was ignoring the BBOX-parameter for layers inherited from QGIS2. I probably need to add them all over again